# Connecting an axle to a stud on the ground for railings

Tags: piece-information, technic, building

I'm trying to build railing using axles and connectors and am not finding an easy way to get the axles that go to the ground to connect in a way that would be best for my design. Three options I've found so far is using [4032](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4032#T=C), [3941](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3941#T=C), or [3713](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3713#T=C). I like 3713 because it has a smaller profile, but it cannot be placed directly on a stud, which causes two problems: 1) the railings are slightly inside of the plate (less problematic to me); 2) I cannot cover the surrounding studs with tiles, which I'd like to do. Seems another option could be using [11458](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11458#T=C). That would also offset the railing, but I could cover the stud with a 1x1 tile. I could also use a technic [3700](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3700#T=C) or [32064](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32064#T=C), but again, offset and you lose the smaller profile. I'm wondering if I'm not missing some socket sticking straight up that would solve the problem.

Comment: While I have a rough understanding, I'm find it a little confusing in terms of exactly what the issue is. Do you have any sort of mock-up to show?

Comment: Is your railing to minifig scale? How long is the vertical axle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

[image]

For the axle with stud on one side you could also use a smaller pin connector 18654.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some Ideas i came up with. I added some of your suggestions for comparrison.

[image]

**Mounted on top of the plate:**

1. 4032
2. 3941
3. 3713
4. 11458, 32013, 2780
5. 30383, 30553

**Mounted below the plate:**

6. 40902, 30552
7. 30389b, 30553
8. 32000, 32013, 2780
9. 3701, 32013, 2780

Comment: Uli got me the exact answer I needed, but I upvoted this one too, really appreciate the effort here!